# typedef char * pChar and const pChar

Tags: c++

typedef char * pChar

typedef const char * pConstChar

I find

const pChar is **char * const**

pConstChar is **const char ***

Am I right?

Comment: Are you right about what, what is the question here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct. It is more obvious when writing the `const` at the correct side of the type, i.e., always putting it on the right:

```
const pChar
```

is identical to

```
pChar const
```

which is identical to

```
char* const
```